# mfmailcomposeviewcontroller error 'MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly' only on ios 9 simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios9

Recently I upgraded to Xcode 7.0.1 and running on iOS 9 Simulator,I started facing error 'MailcompositionService quit unexpectedly'

My Email Button Click's code:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"example@example.com", nil]];
    
    NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString* version = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    
    [composer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n App Version %@ \n iOS Version %@", version, ver] isHTML:NO];
    
    int count = 1;
    for (NSString *fullPath in [DeviceLoger getLogFilesPath])
    {
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        [composer addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Log_File_%d",count]];
        count++;
    }
    
    
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        composer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [ROOT_VIEW_CONTROLLER presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else
        [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
    [Utility showDialog_OK:nil withMessage:NO_EMAIL_SETUP andButton:@"OK"];
```

Also Delegate Method gives error as nil:

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
if(error)
{
    [Utility showAlertWithTitle:@"" message:@"Error sending messaage. Please try again." delegate:nil tag:0 buttons:@[@"Ok"]];
}
else
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [controller release];
    }];
} }
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I have a bad feeling about [controller release]. Maybe Apple has ruled it out in the iOS 9.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201016/why-is-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-crashing-on-ios-8-3/30201362#30201362

Comment: It fails on simulator but working on the actual device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078073/